# Do 2 timeseries represent the input better than one?

Tags: signal-processing, information-theory

I only have a very basic familiarity with signal processing and information theory so I'm sorry if this is a very straight forward question.

I have a very brief input signal and two timeseries as outputs (0s and 1s only). I would like to look at methods that will enable me to quantify whether I can better predict or represent the input with both of these timeseries as opposed to just one. I have a baseline for both my output signals (pre input onset). Both output signals are responding to the same input occurring at the same time.

Edit 1: From what I understand the system is probably time-invariant but there's a good chance it's not linear. Maybe I should start by treating it as an LTI system for simiplicity.

Comment: What's the process by which the output signals are generated? For instance, is it an LTI system?